# Сработает ли такое экранирование против SQL инъекций?

Tags: sql

Псевдокод на JS:

```
function a(id) {
  const query = `SELECT * FROM `users`, where id = ${id}`;
}
```

Это запрос, как я понимаю, уязвим.

А если обернуть id в ковычки (`'${id}'`), это решит вопрос?

```
function a(id) {
  const query = `SELECT * FROM `users`, where id = '${id}'`;
}
```

Comment: ахахахах....нет......

Comment: А что, в ковычках Union сработает?))

Comment: Почитай что такой sql инъекция и как они делаются. Этот пример думаю как базовый пример везде есть

Comment: какой union, о чём ты? откуда он вообще взялся

Comment: Да я понимаю что это. Мне больше интересно, что делает escape функции. И нужно ли мне для этого искать и ставить библиотеку.

Comment: https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection/union-attacks

Comment: Для защиты от инъекций используют соответсвующие расширения или библы...как правило библы работы с БД  для работы с подготовленными переменными